# I want to get value or zero for display if id has a record in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent-relationship, laravel-relations

This is about Laravel query. I want get some data from db. I used below code for it,

```
$ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
$stock = $item->stocks->whereIn('paperorder_paper_id', $ids)->where('status', 'qc-pass')->get();
```

When simplified My problem is if id no **1** has a record it should display that value otherwise should display zero ("0"). Because I want to put data in to datable. Please see the image. Then clearly understand what is my problem.

Expected:
[image]

Problem and I got the result
[image]

stocks DB

```
    Id  Value
    1       
    2   120
    3   50
    4   
    5   1000
```

below has my real code in the blade file. But complicated to explain using real code. Please help me solved this thing.

```
<td class="border-t border-gray-200 border-dashed">
                                @php
                                    $paperorderids = [];
                                    $paperorder = $item->paperorders->where('paperorder_id', $item->id);

                                    foreach ($paperorder as $key => $value) {
                                        $paperorderids[] = $value->id;
                                    }

                                    // Output: $ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

                                    $stock = $item->stocks->whereIn('paperorder_papers_id', $paperorderids)->where('status', 'qc-pass');
                                    // Output: 2 arrays only becasue others id has not record thats why I want zero for that.

                                    foreach ($stock as $key => $val) {
                                        echo $val->qty ? $val->qty : 0; 
                                    }
                                    // 
                                @endphp

                                {{-- @foreach ($item->paperorders as $paperorder)

                                    @foreach ($item->stocks as $stock)
                                        @if ($paperorder->id == $stock->paperorder_papers_id && $stock->status === 'qc-pass')
                                            <span class="flex items-center px-6 py-0 text-gray-700">
                                                {{ $stock->qty }}
                                            </span>
                                        @else
                                            <span class="flex items-center px-6 py-0 text-gray-700">
                                                0
                                            </span>
                                        @endif

                                    @endforeach


                                @endforeach --}} 


                            </td>
```

Comment: you can used in balde {{$id ? $id : 0}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help me here is my final code and it's worked for me.

```
@php
 $stock = $item->stocks->where('status', 'qc-pass');
 $stockids = [];
 foreach ($stock as $key => $sids) { $stockids[] = $sids->paperorder_papers_id;}
@endphp

@foreach ($item->paperorders as $val)
  <span class="flex items-center px-6 py-0 text-gray-700">
     @if (in_array($val->id, $stockids))
     {{ $item->stocks->where('paperorder_papers_id', $val->id)->where('status', 'qc-pass')->sum('qty'); }}
      @else
        0
     @endif
   </span>
@endforeach
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2kMa.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

That should do it.

```
echo in_array($val->id, $ids) ? $val->qty : 0;
```

Comment: No sir it couldn't work for me.  output came as 00. Any idea do it inside of blade foreach directly. this is the my main queries and "$this->paperorders = paperorder::with('order','client','paperorders','papers','stocks')->get();"

Comment: In the blade just use `{{ in_array($val->id, $ids) ? $val->qty : 0 }}`